# Android Log.d does not print whole message

Tags: android, uri, android-logcat

I want `Log.d` to print out a uri so I coded

```
Log.d(uri.toString(), "TOKEN");
```

Later on, I run a `split` method on the uri and have `Log.d` print the second half of the original uri. Surprisingly, the printed content was longer than what was printed in the first time.

I think Log.d is not printing the whole uri. How do I make Log.d log out everything in the uri?

Comment: the first argument in `Log.d` is `identifier` and the 2nd is `content`. you should switch these two as : `Log.d("Token",uri.toString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it otherwise:

```
Log.d("TOKEN", uri.toString());
```

The first parameter is the tag.

The 2nd parameter is the message.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: thanks for fast response. Do you mean in Log.d(string a, string b), the string a must not exceed 15 characters? My uri definitely has more than 15 characters.

Comment: Thats true, the first one (String a) is the tag. The 2nd (String b) is the message. See updated answer

Comment: OMG, I've been using Log.d wrong this whole time! I've always switched the position of the two strings. Thank you so much. Without you I may keep using it the wrong way for the rest of my life.

Comment: No problem, happy to help ;)